# How to change the color of only a part of this line in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

In the following image, want the cat head black and the shape of the heart in orange.

[image: my image]

I tried selecting the line that I want but it only selects all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to colour the shape that makes up the cat's head, it would need to be a separate closed path. One closed path can only have one fill colour (unless it's filled with a gradient obviously).

A simple solution might be to draw a straight line from the node that forms the corner, to overlap the other edge. Select both the line and shape, then do a Division boolean operation <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>.

Then you will be able to select the head shape and apply a fill to it.

Example

[image]

From this point you could edit the paths, to separate the shapes further

Example:

[image]

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks so much Billy. I'm new to Inkscape and this may be a silly question - how do you select the 'cusp node' option? Thank you, A

Comment: @Alex It's in the snap controls bar.  Hit the following buttons: Enable snapping, Snap nodes paths and handles, Snap cusp nodes.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks so much! This is what I have gotten to.. after 45 minutes:
https://www.loom.com/share/14cb1b9f15de495489b7b1daf148070d